# Does "odds-on favourite" mean more than 50% chance?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

My understanding is that "odds-on" and the phrase "odds-on favourite" do not have the exact same meaning.

1. Odds-on: More than likely to happen, so more than 50% probability.
2. Odds-on favourite: "a person, team, horse, etc that is regarded as the most likely to win a competition". In this case, I don't believe it necessarily has to be more than 50% probability; just more probable than the other options.

Please confirm if "odds-on favourite" needs to mean more than 50% likely or not..

Comment: Most likely, not necessarily 50% or more.

Comment: Would you be able to tell us the source of those definitions?

Comment: It is a hopeless task to try to attach a firm meaning to the term.

Comment: Your understanding that "odds-on" can only be understood in the terms of horse racing betting (or similar gambling pursuits). -- A favourite can be 2-1 (you bet £10, and you win £20 and you get your £10 back) or it can be 2-1 **on** You bet £10, and you win £5, and get your money back. -- the implication is that an "odds on" favourite is more likely to win than a favourite.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include in your question your own research on *odds-on*, which was clearly consistent with (for example):

> Odds-on = having or viewed as having a better than even chance to win
> “the odds-on favorite”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odds-on)

The odds are the ratio of one outcome to the others. For example:

> Odds. Ratios of probabilities, they can be defined in two different ways: odds in favor of an event ("odds on") or against an event A ("Odds Against).  Odds can be expressed as a ratio of the probability an event will happen divided by the probability an event won't happen: Odds in favor of A = A / (1 - A), usually simplified to lowest terms., For instance, if the probability of an event occurring is 0.75, then the odds for it happening are 0.75/0.25 = 3/1 = 3 to 1 for, while the probability that it doesn't occur is 1 to 3 against.
>
> [Data science](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/odds-vs-probability-vs-likelihood)

With all this in mind it is clear that the odds-on favorite has a better than even (more than 50%) chance of winning, leaving less than 50% chance of winning to any or all of the others. There can therefore be only one such odds-on favorite.

This negates your second option.

Comment: Isn't 'You forgot to include in your question your own research on _odds-on_' in an answer inconsistent with the aims of ELU? The question, if easily answered as here, should just  be CV-ed, or if important non-basic points can be made, edited into an acceptable form (here editing, adding research,  would show how basic the question is).

Comment: I believe the research was there but its source was not given. I am not going to ignore a plea for help merely because of such a trivial formal aspect.

Comment: LMGTFY. It devalues the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I doubt Google’s ability to reveal easily to an uninformed questioner the logic of comparing an odds-on favourite (> all others taken together) to the  lesser type of favourite (> any one of the others). And that comparison is crucial to the matter, despite the ease with which one might Google *odds* or *favourite*. I may of course be wrong but life is too short to wander overlong in Google when the answer is simple to find in one’s own head.